# Building medium size android application is very slow

Tags: android

My application has a bunch of external .jars, android libraries, and a plenty of code. Bulding the project (I am using eclipse) is terrible. It takes few minutes to do clean/build. And after each rebuild I have to restart eclipse, otherwise it just hangs on second build. I am afraid that soon I'll not be able to build it at all!! Giving more memory to Eclipse has no effect.

On the other side, there is absolutely no problems building small android applications.

I am on Windows Vista, eclipse-java-galileo-SR2, Android SDK Tools (revision8), Core 2 Duo 2GHz.

**Q:** It would be great to hear from other developers having pretty big projects, if you have same issues, and how you solve them?

An other issue that I see, is that compilation hangs some times since it can't communicate with emulator. If I close emulator, it may complete.

Comment: are there other projects open in your eclipse workspace(android or otherwise) that are open?  If so you may want to try and close those projects, or set them not build automatically.  Also you could check the number of plugins you have installed in eclipse.  It sounds more like an eclipse issue w/ the setup than a project specific issue. Also how many external jars is a bunch?  I have had projects w/ about 5 external jars and internal code w/ no issues.

Comment: The only issue I've had with slow building time has been when I overload the resource folder with images.  A current project of mine has over 200 images spread between resource density folders.  Twice, I've actually taken 90% of the images out, just for faster build times.  With all the images, I've had build times upwards of three minutes.  Pretty horrible when your trying to debug and building constantly.

Comment: I have ~8 external jars, ~8 referenced Java projects, 1 referenced Android library. So it's hard to say, what really affects the speed. Continue experimenting... Also, I tried to compile a simple project with all my resources (without code), and it compiled very fast. But again, may be when every thing combined, it takes long.

Answer (score 1):

I added more physical memory. Running eclipse with such parameters:

```
eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xmx700M
```

Now I have more than enought of memory. It is ~1Gb of extra free RAM available.

Project rebuild takes ~1m 10s, that is about twice faster than it used to be, but on the other side this is still not ideal.

An other positive effect - I don't have to restart eclipse after each rebuild any more.